# Selecting search result template by result type is missing mapped properties in template

Tags: 2013, display-template, search-results-webpart, result-types

I've used the techniques in [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tothesharepoint/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-results-option-1) to add a couple new managed properties to my custom item template which is selected by a search result type and has been working for several years. The correct template is selected but the mapped properties I added are not returned.

If I look at the refiners available to the search web part I see the added properties from the template. But they do not appear in the item information returned by the search.

The mapped properties are returned as expected when the search web part sets the template explicitly with the "Use a single template to display items" option.

Answer (score 0):

After contacting Microsoft support and much more digging we discovered the admin master page in our dev environment had been mangled and was missing the PageStatusBar containing the "Update" link.
In the process we confirmed the "Update" link calls the javascript function SyncProperties().